# Kendo UI Grid Editor Complete

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid, where I have defined an Editor like this:

```
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Data)
        .Name("GridINT")
        .Editable(editable => editable
            .Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
            .TemplateName("MyTemplateName")
            .Window(w => w.Width(500))
            .Window(w => w.Title("My Template")))
```

Before I engage the editor, I bind a mouseup handler to the rows, and I tweak the style of the command button.  When the editor closes, whether by Submit, Cancel, or 'X', my handler and style tweaks are gone for the affected row.  I need to restore them, but I haven't found the valid event.  I have bound the cancel click event like this:

```
    $('.k-grid-cancel').bind('click', function ( e ) {
    colorCommandCells();
});
```

but if I restore my handler/style to a grid row here, the editor's closing process undoes what I have done.

Bottom line:  how can I know that the editor is finished updating the grid (which it does, as I have described, even if the editor is cancelled) and which row was the one that the editor messed with?

This is the code that colors the command cells:

```
    function colorCommandCells() {
    // This block colors the command cell according to ISNEW.  It must run every time the DataBound event occurs.
    var grid = $("#GridINT").data("kendoGrid");
    var gridData = grid.dataSource.view();
    for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
        var currentUid = gridData[i].uid;
        var currentRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
        var editButton = $(currentRow).find(".k-grid-edit");
        var aColor = gridData[i].ISNEW == 1 ? "#FFCCFF" : "transparent";
        var aText = gridData[i].ISNEW == 1 ? "Add" : "Edit";
        var parent = $(editButton).closest("td");
        $(parent[0]).css('background-color', function () { return aColor; });
        editButton[0].innerHTML = "<span class=\"k-icon k-edit\"></span>" + aText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically the Grid is rebound each time after such operations, and it is good  to either use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/on/) events attached to the tbody of the Grid or bind the events each  time when the [dataBound](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-dataBound) event of the Grid occurs.

Comment: I have a handler for DataBound, but it does not hit when I cancel the editor.  Nor are the other rows (the ones not involved in the edit) affected.  DataBound hits if I filter the grid, but (apparently) not just because I edit a row.

Comment: Then the handler should remain, How you bind that mouseup handler?

Comment: Originally, I was using $('.k-grid-content tr').bind('mouseup'....  When I converted to the delegate approach, $('.k-grid-content tbody).on('mouseup', 'tr'..., the handler remained.  However (no fair! two-part question), the style changes (I edited the question to show that code), which are not event-driven, are still lost.  If I add a 1-second timer to the click handler (above), I can restore the style.  This tells me that there is something happening after the cancel event, that, if I wait for it, I am OK....

Comment: Still outstanding is the question: how can I know that the editor is completely finished updating the grid (which it does, as described, even if the editor is cancelled and which it does AFTER calling the Sync or Cancel Events)?

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this answer:  First, when building the DataSource for the Grid, assign a function to the Sync Event.

```
.Events(e => e.Sync("syncGrid"))
```

Also, when building the Grid, assign a function to the Cancel event.

```
.Events(e => e.DataBound("gridIsDataBound").Cancel("cancelEditor").Edit("gridEdit"))
```

You have to have both, because the Sync event will fire if the popup editor is closed via "Submit" and the Cancel event will fire if the popup editor is closed via "Cancel" or "X".   Both functions should call something like this, where colorACommandCell is where I restore my style values:

```
function closeEditor() {
    var timer;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(colorACommandCell, 100);
}
```

There is still some activity related to the Grid that occurs after the editor closes (this is what clobbers my style tweaks).  I found that, if I queued up my "fixes" to wait 0.1 seconds, then they would not get overwritten.  Ideally, however, I'd like to have a more certain event that fires when the Editor is REALLY finished.  I don't expect to be able to trust this timer on every machine that runs my code.

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question:  how can I know that the editor is finished updating the grid (which it does, as described, even if the editor is cancelled)?